# MergeSort on Linked List -- getting Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote the following code to perform Mergesort on Linked List but I'm getting Segmentation fault...
I'm not knowing where I have coded wrongly.
the steps I have followed:

1. first I find the middleNode
2. I will perform mergesort on first half and second half of the LinkedList.
3. After that I merged the 2 Linked Lists.
4. I returned the head of the sorted Linked List
   Pls help me out.

```
#mergesort

class Solution{
  public:

    Node* findmiddle(Node* head){
     
        Node* slow=head,*fast=head->next;
        while(fast!=NULL && fast->next!=NULL){
                slow=slow->next;
                fast=fast->next->next;
            
        }
        return slow;
        
    }
    Node* merge(Node* head1,Node* head2){
        if(head1==NULL){
            return head2;
        }if(head2==NULL){
            return head1;
        }
        Node* res=NULL,*tail=NULL;
        if(head1->data<=head2->data){
            res=head1;
            tail=head1;
            head1=head1->next;
        }else{
            res=tail=head2;
            head2=head2->next;
        }
        while(head1!=NULL && head2!=NULL){
            if(head1->data<=head2->data){
                tail->next=head1;
                tail=tail->next;
                head1=head1->next;
            }else{
                tail->next=head2;
                tail=tail->next;
                head2=head2->next;
            }
            
        }
        if(head1!=NULL){
            tail->next=head1;
        }else{
            tail->next=head2;
        }
        return res;
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    Node* mergeSort(Node* head) {
        // your code here
        if(head==NULL && head->next!=NULL){
            return head;
        }
        Node* middle=findmiddle(head);
        Node* head2=middle->next;
        middle->next=NULL;
        Node* temp1=mergeSort(head);
        Node* temp2=mergeSort(head2);
        Node* res=merge(temp1,temp2);
        return res;
        
        
    }
};
```

what's wrong with my code.

Comment: add the tag of the programming language you're using.

Comment: You can check this geeksforgeeks link for better understanding [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/). Hope this post may solve your problem.

Comment: `if(head==NULL && head->next!=NULL)` is one problem (if head is NULL, looking at its `->next` is not a good idea)